# How to extract the argument of actix_web HttpServer::new(..) into a separte function?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am trying to extract the `factory` closures into it's own function.

So instead of this

```rust
let server = HttpServer::new(|| App::new().wrap(Logger::default()))
    .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
    .run();
```

I'd like to move `App::new()...` into a new function called `new_app()`

```rust
let server = HttpServer::new(|| new_app())
                        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?.run();

// todo
fn new_app() { todo!() }
```

I was unable to use Clion IDE or VSCode do it automatically as they are unable to figure out the return type of `App::new().wrap()..`

However I figured the return type is something like this

```rust
pub fn new_app() -> App<
    impl ServiceFactory<
        ServiceRequest,
        Config = (),
        Response = ServiceResponse<
            actix_web::middleware::logger::StreamLog<actix_web::body::AnyBody>,
        >,
        Error = Error,
        InitError = (),
    >,
    actix_web::middleware::logger::StreamLog<actix_web::body::AnyBody>,
> {
    App::new().wrap(Logger::default())
}
```

However this can not be right because the module `actix_web::middleware::logger` is private.

So I tried with a more "generic" type of the generic type parameters,

```rust
pub fn new_app() -> App<
    impl ServiceFactory<ServiceRequest>,
    impl MessageBody,
> {
    App::new().wrap(Logger::default())
}
```

However this also doesn't compile with this error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `App<impl ServiceFactory<ServiceRequest>, impl MessageBody>: actix_service::IntoServiceFactory<_, Request>` is not satisfied
  --> src/app.rs:79:78
   |
79 |         let server = HttpServer::new(|| new_app_2()).bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?.run();
   |                                                                              ^^^ the trait `actix_service::IntoServiceFactory<_, Request>` is not implemented for `App<impl ServiceFactory<ServiceRequest>, impl MessageBody>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <App<T, B> as actix_service::IntoServiceFactory<actix_web::app_service::AppInit<T, B>, Request>>
```

It seems like a trivial work to extract some code into a function but I am not sure how to fix this. Would you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issue by implementing custom logging middleware.

Then we can use `actix_web::dev::Body` instead of  `actix_web::middleware::logger::StreamLog<actix_web::body::AnyBody>`.

```
use actix_service::ServiceFactory;

fn app() -> App<
    impl ServiceFactory<
        Request = actix_web::dev::ServiceRequest,
        Config = (),
        Response = actix_web::dev::ServiceResponse,
        Error = actix_web::Error,
        InitError = (),
    >,
    actix_web::dev::Body, // <- This
> {
     App::new()
        .wrap(middlewares::logging::Logging)
        .service(index)
}
```

As a side note,
You can implement middleware referring official examples https://github.com/actix/examples/tree/master/basics/middleware/src or my code below that includes request & response log.

```
#![allow(unused_imports)]
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use futures::{future::{ok, Future, Ready}, stream::StreamExt};

use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{Value, json};

use actix_service::{Service, Transform};
use actix_web::{
    dev::{ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse},
    web::{Bytes, BytesMut},
    web,
    body::{Body, BodySize, MessageBody, ResponseBody},
    http::Version,
    Error, HttpMessage,
};
use actix_http::h1::{Payload};

use chrono::{Utc, DateTime, Date, NaiveDateTime};

// There are two steps in middleware processing.
// 1. Middleware initialization, middleware factory gets called with
//    next service in chain as parameter.
// 2. Middleware's call method gets called with normal request.
pub struct Logging;

// Middleware factory is `Transform` trait from actix-service crate
// `S` - type of the next service
// `B` - type of response's body
impl<S, B> Transform<S> for Logging
where
    S: Service<Request = ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error> + 'static,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: MessageBody + Unpin + 'static,
{
    type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = LoggingMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ok(LoggingMiddleware {
            service: Rc::new(RefCell::new(service))
        })
    }
}

pub struct LoggingMiddleware<S> {
    service: Rc<RefCell<S>>,
}

impl<S, B> Service for LoggingMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<Request = ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error> + 'static,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: MessageBody + Unpin + 'static,
{
    type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>>>;

    fn poll_ready(&mut self, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        self.service.poll_ready(cx)
    }

    fn call(&mut self, mut req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let mut svc = self.service.clone();

        Box::pin(async move {
            let begin = Utc::now();
            let path = req.path().to_string();
            let method = req.method().as_str().to_string();
            let queries = req.query_string().to_string();
            let ip = req.head().peer_addr;
            let protocol = match req.version() {
                Version::HTTP_09 => "http/0.9",
                Version::HTTP_10 => "http/1.0",
                Version::HTTP_11 => "http/1.1",
                Version::HTTP_2 => "http/2.0",
                Version::HTTP_3 => "http/3.0",
                _ => "UNKNOWN",
            };

            // Request headers
            let mut domain = String::new();
            let mut user_agent = String::new();
            let mut headers: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
            for (k, v) in req.headers().iter() {
                if let Ok(inner) = v.to_str() {
                    let key = k.as_str();
                    headers.insert(key, inner);
                    match key {
                        "host" => { domain = inner.to_string() },
                        "user-agent" => { user_agent = inner.to_string() },
                        _ => {},
                    }
                }
            }
            let req_headers = json!(headers).to_string();

            let req_body = get_request_body(&mut req).await;
            let mut parsed = parse_body(req_body.unwrap());
            let req_body: Option<String> = if ! parsed.is_object() {
                None
            } else {
                /*
                // my code
                // Mask some words for security, like `password`
                for k in vec!["password"] {
                    let obj = parsed.as_object_mut().unwrap();
                    if let Some(p) = obj.get_mut(k) {
                        *p = json!("MASKED_FOR_SECURITY");
                    }
                }
                */
                Some(parsed.to_string())
            };

            // DbPool
            /*
            // my code
            let pool = req.app_data::<web::Data<DbPool>>().map(|p| p.clone());
            */

            // Exec main function and wait response generated
            let mut res = svc.call(req).await?;

            let duration = (Utc::now() - begin).num_microseconds();
            let status_code = res.status();

            // Response headers
            let mut headers: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
            for (k, v) in res.headers().iter() {
                if let Ok(inner) = v.to_str() {
                    headers.insert(k.as_str(), inner);
                }
            }
            let res_headers = json!(headers).to_string();

            // Get response body
            let mut res_body = BytesMut::new();
            let mut stream = res.take_body();
            while let Some(chunk) = stream.next().await {
                res_body.extend_from_slice(&chunk?);
            }

            // Logging
            println!("req.domain  : {:?}", domain);
            println!("req.user_agent  : {:?}", user_agent);
            println!("req.ip  : {:?}", ip);
            println!("req.path  : {:?}", path);
            println!("req.method : {:?}", method);
            println!("req.headers: {:?}", req_headers);
            println!("req.query : {:?}", queries);
            println!("req.body  : {:?}", req_body);
            println!("duration : {:?}", duration);
            println!("res.status : {:?}", status_code);
            println!("res.headers: {:?}", res_headers);
            println!("res.body  : {:?}", res_body);

            /*
            // my code
            let a = AccessLog {
                id: None,
                protocol: Some(protocol.to_string()).into_iter().find(|v| v != ""),
                domain: Some(domain).into_iter().find(|v| v != ""),
                ip: ip.map(|inner| inner.to_string()).into_iter().find(|v| v != ""),
                method: Some(method).into_iter().find(|v| v != ""),
                path: Some(path.to_string()).into_iter().find(|v| v != ""),
                query: Some(queries).into_iter().find(|v| v != ""),
                user_agent: Some(user_agent),
                req_headers: Some(req_headers).into_iter().find(|v| v != ""),
                req_body: req_body,
                duration: duration.map(|inner| inner as i32),
                status_code: Some(status_code.as_u16() as i32),
                res_headers: Some(res_headers).into_iter().find(|v| v != ""),
                res_body: String::from_utf8(res_body.clone().to_vec()).into_iter().find(|v| v != ""),
                others: None,
                requested_at: Some(begin.with_timezone(&*TIMEZONE).naive_local()),
                created_at: None,
            };

            if let Some(pool) = pool {
                if let Ok(conn) = pool.get() {
                    if let Err(e) = a.create(&conn) {
                        eprintln!("database err: {:?}", e);
                    };
                }
            }
            */

            // return original response body
            Ok(res.map_body(|_, _b| ResponseBody::Other(Body::from(res_body))))
        })
    }
}

#[pin_project::pin_project(PinnedDrop)]
pub struct BodyLogger<B> {
    #[pin]
    body: ResponseBody<B>,
    body_accum: BytesMut,
}

#[pin_project::pinned_drop]
impl<B> PinnedDrop for BodyLogger<B> {
    fn drop(self: Pin<&mut Self>) {
        println!("response body: {:?}", self.body_accum);
    }
}

impl<B: MessageBody> MessageBody for BodyLogger<B> {
    fn size(&self) -> BodySize {
        self.body.size()
    }

    fn poll_next(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Option<Result<Bytes, Error>>> {
        let this = self.project();

        match this.body.poll_next(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(Some(Ok(chunk))) => {
                this.body_accum.extend_from_slice(&chunk);
                Poll::Ready(Some(Ok(chunk)))
            }
            Poll::Ready(Some(Err(e))) => Poll::Ready(Some(Err(e))),
            Poll::Ready(None) => Poll::Ready(None),
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
        }
    }
}

async fn get_request_body(req: &mut ServiceRequest) -> Result<BytesMut, Error> {
    // Get body as bytes
    let mut bytes: BytesMut = BytesMut::new();
    let mut body = req.take_payload();
    while let Some(chunk) = body.next().await {
        bytes.extend_from_slice(&chunk?);
    }

    // Set body again
    let (_, mut payload) = Payload::create(true);
    payload.unread_data(web::Bytes::from(bytes.clone()));
    req.set_payload(payload.into());

    Ok(bytes)
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Password {
    password: String,
}

fn parse_body(body: BytesMut) -> Value {
    let json_parsed = serde_json::from_slice::<Value>(&body);
    if let Ok(b) = json_parsed {
        return b
    }
    // let query_parsed = serde_qs::from_bytes::<Password>(&body);
    json!(null)
}
```